# CORS, Azure Mobile Services javascript

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have listed localhost at CORS section in the portal, but i receive this error `Unexpected connection failure` when i send a request to the api endpoint.

Comment: You may need to add the specific port that the local web server is running on, i.e., if you are accessing your client in a browser with an address like http://localhost:8000/, then the CORS domain must be specified as localhost:8000

Comment: This is not a valid host name. You can use wildcard if required ( for example, *.example.com). It told me this when a added the port

Comment: After checking this, specifying just localhost should enable CORS for all ports. You can use * as the hostname to allow all hosts, but this is only advised for a developer site, not for production. Make sure it's a cross domain issue by opening the developer console in your browser and looking at the error message. We can have a closer look if you can provide a little more information such as the operation you are attempting, the exact error message and the browser you are using.

Comment: This is the exact error message _Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://<name-of-mobile-service>.azure-mobile.net/api/users. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'localhost')._ _Azure Error: Unexpected connection failure._. Im using custom authentication which works fine, after the user is authenticated, `https://<name-of-mobile-service>.azure-mobile.net/api/users` endpoint is hit to return profile of the user. There is where is receive this error message. Im using firefox developer edition (40.0a2)

Comment: This is from IE 10 Version 10.0.9200.17357 SEC7118: _XMLHttpRequest for https://<name-of-mobile-service>.azure-mobile.net/api/users required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)._ 
SEC7119: _XMLHttpRequest for https://<name-of-mobile-service>.azure-mobile.net/api/users required CORS preflight._ 
SEC7120: _Origin http://localhost:3000 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header._ 
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
Azure Error: Unexpected connection failure.

Comment: How are you accessing the client, i.e. what is the address in your browser's location bar?

Comment: localhost:3000 is the address

Comment: I have definitely seen this behavior before, but I'm unable to replicate with simple applications. If this is still causing issues, please feel free to email me at dalander@microsoft.com and we can take a closer look at your service.

Comment: I used * as the host name and it worked. I have to definitely change it during production. Thanks Dale, I will contact you for any issue. Thanks